# Reading and writing different files in their own threads from my main loop in C++11

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I am trying to understand, then, write some code that has to read from, and write to many different files and do so from the main loop of my application.  I am hoping to use the C++11 model present in VS 2013.

I don't want to stall the main loop so I am investigating spinning off a thread each time a request to write or read a file is generated.

I've tried many things including using the `async` keyword which sounds promising.  I boiled down some code to a simple example:

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool write_file(const std::string filename)
{
    std::cout << "write_file: filename is " << filename << std::endl;

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));

    std::cout << "write_file: written" << std::endl;

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const std::string filename = "foo.txt";

    auto write = std::async(std::launch::async, write_file, filename);

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "working..." << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
        std::cout << "write result is " << write.get() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I'm struggling to understand the basics but my expectation would be that this code would constantly print "working..." and interspersed in the output would be the write_file start and end messages. Instead, I see that the `write_file` thread seems to block the main loop output until the timer expires.

I realize I need to also consider mutex/locking on the code to actually write the file but I would like to understand this bit first.

Thank you if you can point me in the right direction.

Molly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`write.get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get) will wait for the async task to finish. You want to use [`wait_for()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for) instead:

```
do {
    std::cout << "working...\n";
} while(write.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100)) != std::future_status::ready);

std::cout << "write result is " << write.get() << "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you - that worked perfectly.  I have a follow up questions - I have a feeling it's recommended to make a new post but since it's related, I'll try here first.

What is the recommended way to extend this model so that I can continually be creating writes and reads?  Add a generator function in the do loop that adds a read or write as needed, stores the promise and then extend the wait_for test to wait for them all to complete?  

I was about to try that but it seems clumsy given the elegance of what you just showed me so I figured I would check.

Comment: There are many possible approaches, and it depends on exactly when and how you start more async tasks. But maybe you can simplify the problem by not showing `"working..."` in a loop in the main thread. If you really need to show some progress, maybe that can be another async task that shows that message in a loop until you signal it that you are done (this can be done efficiently with a [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)).

Comment: Understood.  I think the way I'm going to structure it is to have functions to request a file write or file read from elsewhere in the application, and something in the main loop that initiates and serves each one.  Fun stuff and thank you again for your help.

Comment: I posted a follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63065039/protecting-read-write-access-to-from-a-file-from-multiple-threads)