# Protecting read/write access to/from a file from multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, c++11

This is a follow on from a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63060346/reading-and-writing-different-files-in-their-own-threads-from-my-main-loop-in-c) - I received some wonderful advice that helped me move my code along. For the next piece of the puzzle, I figured it warranted a new post - I hope that's okay.

I have some code that creates requests in a main loop, to read from or write to a file and executes each request in its own thread. With the help I got from the earlier post, I was able to extend my code to add a request queue with multiple entries and read/write functions that merely sleep for a short time to emulate file access.

Now I want to actually learn how to read and write to/from the files when there can potentially one or more threads trying to read and/or write the same file at the same time.

To make this easier to test, I limit the file to a single instance otherwise I need to consider the cases where the file doesn't exist etc. In the real application, there will be several hundred files in play but my limited understanding suggests that if I can make the locking mechanism work for a single file, it'll work when there are many.

I am still trying improve my understanding of threading and first tried adding an `std::mutex` with a global lock variable in the `read_file()` & `write_file()` functions but I got into a terrible mess.

Can someone please point me at the correct approach I should investigate to make this work in a robust fashion.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <random>

std::vector< std::future<std::string> > requests;

int random_int(int start, int end)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 generator(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(start, end);

    return distrib(generator);
}

const std::string generate_filename()
{
    std::ostringstream filename;

    // use a single file for testing
    //filename << "file_" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << random_int(1, 20) << ".txt";

    filename << "file.txt";

    return filename.str();
}

std::string write_file(const std::string filename)
{
    std::cout << "write_file: filename is " << filename << std::endl;

    // slow things down so i can follow
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

    std::ofstream ofs(filename);
    if (!ofs)
    {
        return std::string("ERROR");
    }

    const char chr = 'A' + random_int(0, 25);
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
    {
        ofs << chr;
    }
    ofs << std::endl;
    ofs.close();

    std::cout << "write_file: written to " << filename << std::endl;

    return std::string("WRITTEN");
}

std::string read_file(const std::string filename)
{
    std::cout << "read_file: filename is " << filename << std::endl;

    // slow things down so i can follow
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

    std::ifstream ifs(filename);
    if (!ifs.is_open())
    {
        return std::string("ERROR OPEINING FILE");
    }

    std::string contents;
    if (std::getline(ifs, contents))
    {
        std::cout << "    read_file: read from " << filename << std::endl;
        return std::string(contents);
    }

    return std::string("ERROR READING CONTENTS");
}

void add_request()
{
    // randomly add a read or a write request
    if (random_int(1, 50) > 25)
        requests.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, write_file, generate_filename()));
    else
        requests.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, read_file, generate_filename()));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int max_requests = 10;

    // avoid falling out of the loop on first pass
    add_request();

    do {
        std::cout << "working: requests in queue = " << requests.size() << std::endl;

        // randomly add a request if we still have not added the max
        if (random_int(1, 5) == 1)
        {
            if (--max_requests > 0)
            {
                add_request();
            }
        }

        // service the future for each item in the request queue
        for (auto iter = requests.begin(); iter != requests.end(); )
        {
            if ((*iter).wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1)) == std::future_status::ready)
            {    
                std::cout << "Request completed, removing it from the queue: result: " << (*iter).get() << std::endl;
                iter = requests.erase(iter);
            }
            else
            {
                ++iter;
            }
        }

    // once the queue is empty we exit - in the real app, we do not 
    // and keep processing requests until the app exits normally
    } while (requests.size() > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the algorithm each thread should follow:

1. Acquire the lock that protects the shared state of files.
2. See if the file we are trying to access exists in the table.
3. If it does not exist, create it.
4. Check the entry for the file we are trying to access.
5. If no other thread is accessing the file, jump to step 9.
6. Release the lock that protects the shared state of files.
7. Wait
8. Go to step 1.
9. Mark the file in use.
10. Release the lock that protects the shared state of files.
11. Read or write the file as appropriate.
12. Acquire the lock that protects the shared state of files.
13. Mark the file not in use.
14. Release the lock that protects the shared state of files.

Note that if you use a condition variable to make the wait more efficient, then steps 6, 7 and 8 turn into waiting on the condition variable and then jumping to step 2. Also, you would need to broadcast the condition variable (notify all) before or after step 14. (Preferably before.)

Comment: Thank you David - trying to digest it and add to my code now. What is the preferred mechanism in C++11 to "Acquire the lock that protects the shared state of files." ?

Comment: Take advantage of RAII and use [std::lock_guard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) (or [std::unique_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock)) to hold a [std::mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to what David Schwartz suggests, instead of keeping shared state and using a `std::mutex` to guard it, you could instead make use of your operating system's ability to place locks on files. For example, on any UNIX-like operating system, you can use [`flock()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) to lock a file, either in shared mode (to allow multiple concurrent readers), or exclusive mode (for a single writer). This would even allow multiple instances of your program to run, accessing the same files without stepping on each others toes. The drawback is that it is not portable, and even on platforms that support it there is no way to get the UNIX file descriptor from a `std::ifstream`, so you would have to use the POSIX API to read and write files instead of functions from `<iostream>`. However, since the locks are *advisory*, you could first call POSIX `open()` on the file, lock it, and then create a `std::ifstream` or `std::ofstream`.

Another issue with multiple threads accessing the same file is that, even if you do proper locking, there is no guarantee in which order the threads are run. Perhaps it is better to not start all operations in parallel, but rather have a per-file queue of pending operations, and have only one thread per file processing these pending operations.

Comment: Thank you for your continued assistance G. Sliepen.  I was experimenting with David's proposal and am still tying myself in knots. I'm not able to use flock() I think because this code will ultimately end up running on Windows systems.

Your note about thread timing though made me realize that all I need to do is move the read/write off of the main loop so it doesn't stall - there is no need to have each read/write in its' own thread - so I am going to try to tackle it that way.

Comment: There may well end up being 2 request queues - one for reads (that eventually return a pointer to the loaded data or nullptr if it's not present) and one for writes (that return a bool indicating success/failure).  I know I could make them return the same value but that seemed like a good separation of responsibility and I wasn't able to figure out the semantics of get() to retrieve 2 different return types.

Comment: @MollyBirk: in C++17 you could use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) for that, but you can also just return a `struct` with a `union` of a `bool` and a pointer inside, and another variable to distinguish between reads and writes. But if 2 request queues work then just go with that.

Comment: I now have a global std::deque<> of instances of a small request data class. I have a process_request() function that sits in a loop, popping requests off the deque and acting on them. In my main loop, I randomly add a read/write request to the deque. 

If there is just one function in it's own thread, reading/writing as per the request, am I right in thinking I don't need to worry about locking the files anymore? 

I am also concerned about modifying the std::deque inside and outside of the thread.  Do I need to protect access to the deque with an std::mutex?

Comment: @MollyBirk: having a single thread process the requests in order indeed avoids the need for locking files. You still need to have a lock to ensure modifying the queue is safe from multiple threads. Also, I would recommend you use [`std::queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) instead of `std::deque`. The former uses the latter internally, but restricts the API to do just what a FIFO queue needs to do.

Comment: Thank you - I added some other code to add requests, read/write files then confirm they weren't corrupted. The only piece I am not sure about is what is the right way to add a request (main loop) and remove a request (threaded worker function) - currently I surround the threaded code to remove an entry with 

            my_lock.lock();
            request* req = requests.front();
            requests.pop();
            my_lock.unlock();

where my_lock is an std::mutex.  Is that sufficient or do I need something similar at the point where a request is added in the main loop?

Comment: Final comment.  Both  G. Sliepen and David have been very helpful - should I mark David's reply as the answer even though it wasn't quite right for my eventual use case?

Comment: You should select the answer that is most helpful for the question you have posted. I personally think that David's answer is the more straightforward solution.